# Internal error about compactor in cloudant local docker

Tags: docker, couchdb, cloudant

IBM suggest me to use cloudant docker locally for testing purpose.

This is the image I use https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/cloudant-developer/

It basically works fine most of the time but sometimes I got error like this

```
{
  "error": "{badmatch,{error,enoent}}",
  "reason": "[{couch_mrview_compactor,swap_compacted,2,\n [{file,\"src/couch_mrview_compactor.erl\"},{line,261}]},\n {couch_index,commit_compacted,2,[{file,\"src/couch_index.erl\"},{line,371}]},\n {couch_index,handle_call,3,[{file,\"src/couch_index.erl\"},{line,190}]},\n {gen_server,try_handle_call,4,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,607}]},\n {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,639}]},\n {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,237}]}]",
  "ref": 2090670111
}
```

I don't know where this error came from couchdb itself. Or anything cloudant extended from couchdb. Or the limitation of docker image IBM created. So I'm not sure where I should ask

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The crash is occurring in couchdb code, here:
https://github.com/apache/couchdb-couch-mrview/blob/d4509606f3aacc4bec94b8936bedf6d1d597ff5f/src/couch_mrview_compactor.erl#L261

And the error 'enoent' means that the file it tried to delete doesn't exist.

I've heard other reports of filesystem instability using the developer edition, so I wouldn't be surprised if the problem lies with either the containerization or perhaps even with Docker itself.

Do you see any other evidence of missing files, such as disappearing databases, and the like?

Comment: I see nothing error in the file or database specifically. I think this error only happen when I try to call it too many times or push too many document into it. And it can be retry to get a seemingly a correct result

Comment: Another possibility is that this workflow/configuration is exposing a race condition in the couchdb code. It might be useful to see if you can repro using one of the 2.0.0 images here: https://github.com/apache/couchdb-docker